# How to calculate total press time of button using timer

Tags: timer, pic

I am new to pic controller. I am using pic 16F887. I want to calculate the total time of the button press. And that time I want to use as a delay to blink led. And i can change that button press time to change the delay by replacing the previous delay of the led blink. How do i do that by correcting below code

```
#include <htc.h>
#define _XTAL_FREQ 8000000
#define SWITCH RB0
#define LED RD2



long int total_count = 0,count = 0,count1 = 0;
char flag =0,flag1 =0;
char i=0,k=0;



void Init_Timer1() // Timer Initialization at 0.6ms
{
    TMR1ON   = 0x01;
    TMR1IF   = 0;
    TMR1H    = 0xFB;
    TMR1L    = 0x4F;
    TMR1IE   = 1;
    INTCON  |= 0xC0;
}
void Extern()
{

    INTCON |= 0XD0;
    INTEDG = 1; // Rising Edge Detect
}

void interrupt ISR(void)
{       
   if(INTF)//External Interrupt Flag
   {
       INTF=0;
       TMR1IF = 0;
       TMR1H  = 0xFB;
       TMR1L  = 0x4F;
       TMR1ON = 0x01;  
       count++;
    }

       if(TMR1IF) // Timer1 Interrupt flag 
   {
       TMR1IF = 0;
       TMR1H  = 0xFB;
       TMR1L  = 0x4F;
       TMR1ON = 0x01;
   }  
}

void main()
{    
   Extern();
   Init_Timer1();
   TRISD2 = 0;
   TRISB0 = 1;
   LED=0;

    while(1)
    { 
    if(RB0 == 0 && flag==0)
    {
      flag=1;
    } 
    if(RB0 == 1 && flag==1)
    {

         LED=1;
         for(i=0;i<count;i++);
         LED=0;
         flag1=0;

    }

    }    
}
```

Comment: What is the purpose of flag1?  Once flag is 1, it will remain 1.  flag1 will always remain 0.  Try drawing a flowchart and do a dry run on your code.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to have a grasp of the big ideas, but may have missed a few details.

```
/*
 * File:   main.c
 * Author: dan1138
 * Target: PIC16F887
 * Compiler: XC8 v1.45
 * IDE: MPLABX v5.25
 *
 * Created on March 23, 2020, 4:22 PM
 */

// CONFIG1
#pragma config FOSC = INTRC_NOCLKOUT    // Oscillator Selection bits (INTOSCIO oscillator: I/O function on RA6/OSC2/CLKOUT pin, I/O function on RA7/OSC1/CLKIN)
#pragma config WDTE = OFF               // Watchdog Timer Enable bit (WDT disabled and can be enabled by SWDTEN bit of the WDTCON register)
#pragma config PWRTE = OFF              // Power-up Timer Enable bit (PWRT disabled)
#pragma config MCLRE = ON               // RE3/MCLR pin function select bit (RE3/MCLR pin function is MCLR)
#pragma config CP = OFF                 // Code Protection bit (Program memory code protection is disabled)
#pragma config CPD = OFF                // Data Code Protection bit (Data memory code protection is disabled)
#pragma config BOREN = OFF              // Brown Out Reset Selection bits (BOR disabled)
#pragma config IESO = OFF               // Internal External Switchover bit (Internal/External Switchover mode is disabled)
#pragma config FCMEN = OFF              // Fail-Safe Clock Monitor Enabled bit (Fail-Safe Clock Monitor is disabled)
#pragma config LVP = OFF                // Low Voltage Programming Enable bit (RB3 pin has digital I/O, HV on MCLR must be used for programming)

// CONFIG2
#pragma config BOR4V = BOR40V           // Brown-out Reset Selection bit (Brown-out Reset set to 4.0V)
#pragma config WRT = OFF                // Flash Program Memory Self Write Enable bits (Write protection off)

#include <xc.h>

#define _XTAL_FREQ 8000000ul
#define SWITCH          RB0
#define SWITCH_DIR      TRISB0
#define SWITCH_PRESSED  (0)
#define LED             RD2
#define LED_DIR         TRISD2
#define LED_OFF         (0)
#define LED_ON          (1)
#define GPIO_IN         (1)
#define GPIO_OUT        (0)

volatile unsigned long  ButtonPressedTicks;
volatile unsigned char  ButtonPressedState;
volatile unsigned char  T2_Ticks;
volatile unsigned long  TicksForLedToBlink;


void Init_TIMER2(void) // Initialize TIMER2 to assert an interrupt every 20 milliseconds
{
    TMR2IE = 0;                 // Disable TIMER2 interrupts
    T2CON  = 0;                 // Stop TIMER2
    T2CONbits.T2CKPS = 0b10;    // Set TIMER2 prescale for 1:16
    T2CONbits.TOUTPS = 0b0100;  // Set TIMER2 postscale for 1:10
    PR2 = (_XTAL_FREQ/(4ul*16ul*10ul*50ul))-1ul;
    TMR2IF = 0;                 // Clear pending interrupt requests
    TMR2IE = 1;                 // Enable TIMER2 interrupts
    PEIE   = 1;                 // Enable peripheral interrupts
    T2CONbits.TMR2ON = 1;       // Turn on TIMER2
}

void Init_INT(void)
{
    INTE = 0;                   // Disable external interrupts
    INTEDG = 0;                 // Falling Edge Detect
    INTF = 0;                   // Clear pending interrupt requests
}

void interrupt ISR(void)
{
    // Handle external interrupt assert
    if (INTE)
    {
        if (INTF)
        {
            INTF = 0;
            INTE = 0;               // Disable external interrupts
            LED = LED_ON;
            T2CONbits.TMR2ON = 0;   // Turn off TIMER2
            TMR2 = 0;
            TMR2IF = 0;             // Clear pending interrupt requests
            T2CONbits.TMR2ON = 1;   // Turn on TIMER2
            ButtonPressedTicks = 0;
            ButtonPressedState = 1;
        }
    }

    // TIMER2 interrupt assert
    if (TMR2IE)
    {
        if (TMR2IF)
        {
            TMR2IF = 0;
            T2_Ticks++;
            if(ButtonPressedState == 1)
            {
                if (SWITCH == SWITCH_PRESSED)
                {
                    ButtonPressedTicks++;
                }
                else
                {
                    if(ButtonPressedTicks < 2)      // SWITCH press too short, must be a bounce
                    {
                        ButtonPressedTicks = 0;     // Start over
                        LED = LED_OFF;
                        INTF = 0;
                        INTE = 1;                   // Enable external interrupts
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        TicksForLedToBlink = ButtonPressedTicks;
                    }
                    ButtonPressedState = 2;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

void main(void)
{
    unsigned char T2_TicksStart;
    unsigned char BlinkTicks;
    unsigned long BlinkTime;

    ANSEL = 0;
    ANSELH = 0;

    Init_INT();
    Init_TIMER2();
    LED_DIR    = GPIO_OUT;
    LED        = LED_OFF;
    SWITCH_DIR = GPIO_IN;
    ButtonPressedTicks = 0;
    ButtonPressedState = 0;
    TicksForLedToBlink = 0;
    T2_Ticks = 0;

    GIE = 1;    // Enable the interrupt system

    while (1)
    {
        if((ButtonPressedState == 2) && (TicksForLedToBlink > 0))
        {
            LED = LED_OFF;
            BlinkTime = 0;
            while(BlinkTime < TicksForLedToBlink)
            {
                T2_TicksStart = T2_Ticks;
                BlinkTicks = 0;
                while(BlinkTicks < 1)
                {
                    BlinkTicks = T2_Ticks;
                    BlinkTicks -= T2_TicksStart;
                }
                BlinkTime += BlinkTicks;
            }

            LED = LED_ON;
            BlinkTime = 0;
            while(BlinkTime < TicksForLedToBlink)
            {
                T2_TicksStart = T2_Ticks;
                BlinkTicks = 0;
                while(BlinkTicks < 1)
                {
                    BlinkTicks = T2_Ticks;
                    BlinkTicks -= T2_TicksStart;
                }
                BlinkTime += BlinkTicks;
            }
        }
        if(INTE == 0) INTE = 1;    // Enable external interrupts
    }
}
```

I do not see a clear way to "fix" the code you posted.

This code uses concepts not yet covered by your instructional materials.

If you submit this as your completed assignment your instructor will know you got it from the internet.